# Printing entire scrollable swing component

Tags: java, swing, printing

Is there any way to print the entire contents of a scrollable swing component?

Comment: yes, but for which JComponent(s) from JScrollPane, anyway here is bacis stuff http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html

Comment: How about JList, but keeping in mind this is just a part of an entire window I want to print

Comment: bump, hmmm really I don't know ..., then just print Graphics from whole ViewPort

Comment: Ok, let's say `JList`, which typically appears in a scroll pane but lacks [custom printing support](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/swing.html). Do you want to print the _view_ currently appearing in the viewport? Alternatively, do you want to print a report based on the list's data _model_.

Comment: The entire scrollable JList expanded so the entire thing is viewable.

Answer (score 1):

There's a section in [Advanced Printing](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/advprint.html) on "Components Larger Than One Page". It works for `JTable`, so you'd have to change it to use `JList`.